# How many times were there "Klingons on/off the starboard bow"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, klingon, quotes

There two [excellent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCARADb9asE) [parodies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VEnT11mTnI) contain either the phrase "*Klingons on the starboard bow*" or "*Klingons off the starboard bow*". How many times, if ever, did this exact phrase occur in The Original Series? I can't help but wonder if, like "*beam me up Scotty*", it was zero.

Comment: Only going forward cos we can't find reverse!

Comment: I bet the line can be heard in "Yesterday's Enterprise."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are actually two questions here. I shall take them in order.

### **How many times is the literal phrase "*Klingons on* [or off] *the starboard bow*" spoken in Star Trek: The Original Series?**

**Zero.** There is, however a single mention of the ship's "*starboard bow*" in [TOS: Charlie X](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/8.htm) where we're told:

> **UHURA:** ***Sir, something off our starboard bow.** The message says they're from Thasus.*

This is close enough that it could be the trope originator.

---

### **How many times were there *actually* Klingons on the ship's starboard bow?**

At least once in the TV series. In [TOS: Elaan of Troyius](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/57.htm) a Klingon ship is sighted on a parallel bearing of

> "*mark seven three point five*"

which would place it on the [ship's starboard bow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LC95.jpg).

Comment: How did you verify these?

Comment: @J.Mini - I used Chakoteya to find each instance of the word "[starboard](http://search.freefind.com/find.html?oq=starboard&id=98804524&pageid=r&_charset_=UTF-8&bcd=%C3%B7&scs=1&query=%22starboard%22+and+%22+The+Star+Trek+Transcripts%22&Find=Search&mode=ALL&search=all)" for the first part, and each instance of the word "Klingon" for the second half, then skimmed through each episode mentioned, just to double-check.